# Link back to mathoverflow

Tags: feature-request, status-norepro

The old meta had a convenient link back to the main mathoverflow site, but that seems to have vanished.  It would be nice to have it back.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have it on the top bar, right by your user name and reputation: "[main](https://mathoverflow.net/)".

Comment: OK, thanks, I missed that.